# Expresion regular php entre tags

Tags: php, regex

Necesito obtener este numero 2769 dentro de estos tags con una expresion regular en php

```
<td style="background-color:#b0c400;border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;text-align:right;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;color:#000000;">2769</td>
```

intente hacerlo asi pero no me funciono

```
preg_match_all("/0px 5px 0px 5px;color:#000000;\"\>'(\d+)'\</", $web, $apies);
```

Comment: Por que debe ser con expresiones regulares? y no con ids?

Comment: como con Id? no entiendo

Comment: el tag `<td>` puede llevar el atributo `id` para acceder a su valor

Comment: no tiene id ese tag y no puedo agregarselo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En caso de que la única forma de sacar ese número sea por los estilos del td prueba con esto:

```
$texto = 'xxxxxx <td style="background-color:#b0c400;border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;text-align:right;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;color:#000000;">2769</td> xxxxxx';

$expr_reg = '%<td style="background-color:#b0c400;border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;text-align:right;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;color:#000000;">(\d*?)</td>%si';
if (preg_match($expr_reg, $texto, $coincidencias)) {
    # Successful match
    print_r($coincidencias);
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
    echo "Mala suerte";
}
```

En *$coincidencias[1]* tienes tu número

Si lo quieres probar antes: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27045ead428f5e61f4d237fe40d3446a819ed09b

Answer (score 1):

No deberías usar expresiones regulares para procesar HTML. Tan sólo un pequeño cambio en el HTML haría que tu regex falle. Un espacio de más, un cambio en los atributos del tag, un comentario, o estructuras más complejas, harían que hasta un regex gigantesco no siga las reglas.

Es muy sencillo procesar HTML con **[DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)**, son las herramientas que están pensadas para eso.

Simplemente se genera el DOM así:

```php
$html = '<td style="background-color:#b0c400;border-bottom:1px solid #ffffff;text-align:right;padding:0px 5px 0px 5px;color:#000000;">2769</td>';

//Generar el DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NONET);
```

Y podemos obtener todo el texto sin tags:

```php
//Eliminar todos los tags
$sin_tags = $dom->textContent;

echo "Contenido de texto de toda la página:\n" . $sin_tags;    // => 2769
```

O, si el HTML tiene más tags y sólo te interesa el primer `<td>`:

```php
//Obtener todos los TD
$td_nodelist = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
//Obtener el primer TD
$td = $td_nodelist->item(0);

//Obtener el contenido de texto del tag
$numero = $td->textContent;

echo "\n\nContenido del TD:\n" . $numero;    // => 2769
```

Resultado:

```
Contenido de texto de toda la página:
2769

Contenido del TD:
2769
```

Demo:

[<kbd>Ver la demo en ideone.com</kbd>](http://ideone.com/YKrpgr)