# Obtener todas las coincidencias entre 2 textos fijos

Tags: php, html, regex

Estoy usando regex para obtener todos los resultados de buscar en una página:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">(NÚMERO ILIMITADO DE CARACTERES)</div>
```

En principio creo que lo tengo bien, pero no me funciona.

```
$regex = '/\<div class\=\"col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4\"\>(.*?)\<\/div\>/';

if(preg_match($regex, $html, $match)) {

    echo $match[0];

}
```

¿Alguien me puede orientar?

Answer (score 1):

[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) devuelve sólo el primer resultado.

> ```
> int preg_match ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = 0 [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
> ```
>
> Busca en **subject** una coincidencia con la expresión regular dada en **pattern**.

[preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match-all.php) devuelve ***todos*** los resultados.

> ```
> int preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags = PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
> ```
>
> Busca en **subject** todas las coincidencias de la expresión regular dada en **pattern** y las introduce en **matches** en el orden especificado por **flags**.
>
> Después haber encontrado la primera coincidencia, las búsquedas subsiguientes continuarán desde el final de la dicha coincidencia.

---

Por otro lado, el punto (`.`) coincide con todos los caracteres *excepto* los saltos de línea, a menos que se especifique el modificador `SINGLELINE` o `/s`.

---

La siguiente expresión regular coincide con el texto publicado en la pregunta (no hay diferencias con el patrón de la pregunta, sólo no estoy escapando los caracteres innecesarios, pero no tiene inferencia sobre el resultado):

```
/<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">(.*?)<\/div>/s
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/dEg7rY/2

---

> **Nota importante**:
>
> Sin embargo, para extraer texto de un HTML, **no se debería usar
>   expresiones regulares**. En cambio, la forma correcta de realizarlo es
>   utilizando el [DOM](http://php.net/manual/es/book.dom.php).
>
> Hay una infinidad de ejemplos que se pueden dar que podrían hacer que
>   cierta expresión falle en un HTML dado (y se podría corregir el regex,
>   pero luego se podría encontrar otra excepción). No tiene ningún
>   sentido reinventar la rueda en este caso. Para eso, hay que usar las
>   herramientas que fueron diseñadas para ese objetivo.

Comment: Ni siquiera me devuelve el primer resultado, es decir, no hay, supongo por ello que el problema está en la la expresión.

Comment: Coincide con el texto que publicaste. En todo caso, por favor actualiza la pregunta con el texto exacto con el que lo estás intentando

Comment: Imagino que el problema es que dentro de lo que seria `(NÚMERO ILIMITADO DE CARACTERES)` seguramente hay tags `HTML` y  puntualmente `div's` que abren y cierran.

Comment: @MarcosGallardo podría haber otras etiquetas, aunque sí fallaría con divs anidados... Una opción eficiente sería adaptar una estructura de _unrolling the loop_, pero creo que escapa al alcance de esta pregunta

Comment: Publiqué un ejemplo usando DOM en http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/30685/127